# php - pass variables through pages and changing it when go back

Tags: php

I'm making a web project in `php` and I have a small problem with understanding how I can get the variables to the next page after clicking on a button.

**Concept**

The concept is simple, - Questions asked by users(with title, the question, author, etc..) and other users can reply a specific question. So the idea is to pass all the info of the particular question into the page were it can be answer.

The most logical solution that I thought saving all the info of the post into `$_SESSION` so it would be more easy to pass to the second page(I think), but the problem is that when the user choose to go back to the previous page all the `$_SESSiON` should be destroyed if the user chooses another question to answer.

**Problem:**
I'm struggling to get that system working

**side note:**

Can it be made by using ajax?

What is the best system for this type os cases?

**CODE**

```
function display_perguntas(){
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];


    $sql = "SELECT * from forum_pergunta where disciplinaID IN (select disciplinaId from users_disciplinas where userID = $userID) AND userID = $userID";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<div class="container">
                    <h2>Questions from my subjects</h2><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                             Title: <strong>'.$row['title'].'</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">
                             Author: '.$row['author'].'
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-3">
                             <h6>Question:</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-9">
                             <textarea readonly style="width: inherit;">'.$row['question'].'</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-5">
                            Subject name: '.$row['subjectID'].'
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            Date: '.$row['date'].'
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="answers_question">Answer Question</button>
                            </form>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <hr>
        </div>';
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you using JS to post your form? The form only contains a button without any specific information/identifier. How are you posting the form and what is the expected result? I would add some hidden fields in the form with the data you want to send and then post it using Ajax.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I was trying to do with ajax but it wasn´t working. if you could comment with an exampleI would be grateful

Comment: I can't write an example since I have no idea what you want to send or what you actually want to do with the result. Show us your attempt and we can take it from there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson [link](https://pastebin.com/gwyZYgzG) here it is my try but like i said it wasn't working

Comment: SO is a site for when you're having issues with your code. If it isn't working, then you should add that code into the question itself (not as an external link) and explain what happens when you run it and what the expected result is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the question data is in the database I suggest using the query string `$_GET` for this (this also means your user can always navigate to an old question from their browser history).

To do this, you'd get rid of that form (that isn't really doing anything) and replace it with a link `<a href="/answer_question.php?question_id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="button">` (assuming your row has an id called id and your css `.button` makes the link look like you want).

Then in answer_questions.php you just need to do `$id = $_GET['id'];` and then plug that into your database so you can display the question and build a form to answer it.

Comment: solved, the problem was that the `<a>`tag should look like this: `<a  href="answer_question.php?id=' . $row["disciplinaID"] . ' " class="btn btn-success">Answer Question</a>`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to use $_GET parameters.

The idea is to have the page with questions like:

```
/questions.php
```

And the question page:

```
/question-info.php?id=1
```

If you use mod_rewrite it can be

```
/questions/
/questions/1.html
```

And for better urls you can use slugs than ids

Comment: It looks better :) also it is semantic.... if it ends with a slash it is directory and with extension it is a file

Comment: A URI without an ending slash should be considered a resource, not a file (unless it's for downloading) so it's more common not having an extension. If someone have to write the URL by hand, they will most likely not add `.html` in the end (since it's not very common).

Comment: I can pull up 10 links that says different but that doesn't matter. This is one of those "everyone has their opinion"-type of things. Your suggestion is definitely not wrong, nor are mine so.... It's all about preference (which is why I removed it from my first comment) ... :-)